# Finding all possible numbers that can be formed from digits in the range 0-8 c++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I'm quite stumped at this actually. Im only allowed too use loops and control structures, and arrays. i really have no idea how too do this.

Given a collection of three different decimal digits in the range 0 to 8 and finds all unique decimal number that can be formed from three digits, also sixes can be inverted into nines and vice versa.

For example it is possible to create the following numbers from the digits 0 3 6:

0, 3, 6, 9, 30, 36, 39, 60, 63, 90, 93, 306, 309, 360, 390, 603, 630,
903, 930.

Any idea on how i should approach this? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated, as i'm still learning programming.

Comment: You already know the solution. Think carefully about how you generated the sample list in the question. What algorithm did your brain use? Now, just write the C++ code for that algorithm. It may not be the most optimized way of doing it, but you can optimize later once you get the code working.

Comment: When given a difficult problem, solve a subset of the problem. In this case, start by solving the case of only being given 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: building on top of @Patashu's advice, worry about only 2 digits first, and then it will be easier to come up with test cases that you can verify the algorithm with